# Ruby non_empty? method

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I want to use expression:

```
!([1,2,3] & [43,5]).empty?
=> false
!([1,2,3] & [3,5]).empty?
=> true
```

to check if two arrays contains at least one common value. And I wonder if there is a better way of doing it? Maybe something like:

```
 ([1,2,3] & [3,5]).non_empty?
```

How to write `non_empty?` method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
([1,2,3] & [3,5]).any?
```

Comment: Why this works: Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the block ever returns a value other than false or nil. If the block is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of {|obj| obj} (that is any? will return true if at least one of the collection members is not false or nil.

Answer (score 4):

Technically answered:

```
class Array
    def non_empty?
        !self.empty?
    end
end

puts [1].non_empty?
```

Though `.any?` already seems to exist for that purpose (see JHurra's answer)

Comment: Thanks, technicaly you answered this question, but @JHurrah answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent query would be asking if the array is not blank. The equivalent to `!array.blank?` is `array.present?`

Check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#M000280

Comment: Thanks, but remember it is added in Rails, it's not Ruby.