# What is the opposite method of Array.empty? or [].empty? in ruby

Tags: ruby

I do realize that I can do

```
unless [1].empty?
```

But I'm wondering if there is a method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby non_empty? method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875147/ruby-non-empty-method)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

As well as `#any?` as davidrac mentioned, with [ActiveSupport](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) there's [#present?](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) which acts more like a truth test in other languages. For `nil`, `false`, `''`, `{}`, `[]` and so on it returns false; for everything else true (including 0, interestingly).

Comment: #present? is likely your best bet if you have access to ActiveSupport.

Comment: another vote for this answer: when you are using ActiveSupport (e.g. within a Rails app), you can use #present? for your needs. But the opposite of #present? would actually be #blank? and not #empty?. #blank? has the same "emptiness" definitions as enumerated for #present? in the answer...

Comment: `any?` will be slower than `![].empty?` since `any?` checks for existence of nil elements. While present? and blank? are nice, they are also slower since they have to check if the element `respond_to?(:empty)`. There is no true inverse of `empty?`

Comment: Rails Guide describing [`#present?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark)

Comment: @Schneems I'd love to see some benchmarks done on these.

Comment: Feel free to run them yourself https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips

Answer (score 24):

You may use `[1].any?`, which is actually defined in [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

Note that this will not work in case your array hold only `nil` or `false` values.

Answer (score 8):

```
[nil].any?
=> false
[nil].any? {|something| true}
=> true
[].any? {|something| true}
=> false
[false, false].any? {|something| true}
=> true
[nil, 'g'].any? {|something| true}
=> true
```

Comment: This answer is really confusing. The code snippets that return true are doing that just because of the return value inside the blocks and not because of the values inside the arrays. (examples 4 and 5 are the same). In the case of example 3, the block is never executed because the array is empty.

Answer (score 3):

No single method I know of is going to give you that in Ruby. Key word 'single':

```
[5].size.positive? => true
[5].size.nonzero? => 1

[].size.positive? => false
[].size.nonzero? => nil
```

Both of these are even more useful with the safe navigation operator, since nil returns falsy, meaning negative methods (like #empty?) break down a bit:

```
# nil considered 'not empty' isn't usually what you want
not_empty = proc{|obj| !obj&.empty? }

not_empty.call nil => true
not_empty.call [ ] => false
not_empty.call [5] => true


# gives different 3 answers for the 3 cases
# gives truthy/falsy values you'd probably expect
positive_size = proc{|obj| obj&.size&.positive? }

positive_size.call nil => nil
positive_size.call [ ] => false
positive_size.call [5] => true


# gives truthy/falsy values you'd probably expect
nonzero_size = proc{|obj| obj&.size&.nonzero? }

nonzero_size.call nil => nil
nonzero_size.call [ ] => nil
nonzero_size.call [5] => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

To check for elements in array :
 
 .empty?
 .present?

if a={}
a.any? .nil?
will gives you false.

To check whether or not a field has a non-nil value:

```
.present?
.nil?
.any?
```

Comment: Note that `present?` is Rails / ActiveSupport, not core Ruby.